# How to sort items in symfony's form collection?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to sort `movements` in my form. Is it possible to acheive with `FormBuilder` ?

```
    $builder->add('movements', 'collection', array(
        'type' => movementFormType(),
        'prototype_name' => '__movements__',
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false
    ));
```

I don't want to add this sort to mapping in my config file because this mapping is used in the places where this sort is not required.

Maybe there is a way to change mapping dynamically in controller ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `bo_list`?

Comment: Sorry, this is the same. `bo_list` actually extends a `collection`. I changed to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

i suppose that your main Entity has a OneToMany relation to another Entity.
In this case your main Entity controls the order of the child entity. e.g.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="images", mappedBy="gallery")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"entity_attribute" = "DESC", "another_entity_attribute" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $images;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I precised that I use *yaml* and the question is how to sort collection with FormBuilder